# Putting do/does before the subject in not-question sentences

Tags: grammar

> Only if Cid is a cat **does** Eve **love** him.

When using this structure should I always break **loves** to **does love** (with subsequent using **does** in front)? Can I just write:

> Only if Cid is a cat Eve **loves** him.

What about just **love** as in **they love**. What can I write:

> Only if Cid is a cat they **love** him.
>
> Only if Cid is a cat **do** they **love** him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examples 2 and 3 are incorrect and would not be used by native English language speakers.

The base example itself is strange as a sentence.  Why not just say "Eve only loves cats" or "Eve only loves animals that are cats"?

A better example is

> "Only when Cid visits is Eleanor happy."

This example is rather literary as speakers are much more likely to say in conversation that "Eleanor is happy only when Cid visits."

Comment: You said example 4 is incorrect. Do you refer to this sentence?: "Only if Cid is a cat do they love him." Why is it incorrect?

Comment: Sorry I corrected that to 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a phrase or clause beginning with "only" or "only if" first to **emphasize** it. You put the subject after an auxiliary verb (be,do, have etc.)in the main clause. This structure is formal or literary.

**Only** in London **did** I find a purpose in life.

**Only** in Paris **do** you find bars like this.

**Only if** these conditions are fulfilled **can** the application proceed to the next stage.

I think the other way you mentioned would be correct as well, but less emphatic and not formal anymore.

Comment: Don't have any idea why that answer got downvoted!